# how to make Card() leading,title,trailing fixed position in flutter

Tags: flutter, position

i'm trying to make nice Card()

there's one problem.

whenever I write so many words in subtilte propertie

***leading, title, trailing*** position changes.

I want these position fixed

as you can see the Star and 'coding' and 'three dots' s postion is moved

[image]

how can I do this?
here's my code

```
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  '⭐️',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.sp),
                ),
                title: Text('coding'),
                subtitle: Text('flutterflutterflutter'),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  '⭐️',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.sp),
                ),
                title: Text('coding'),
                subtitle: Container(
                    child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                        'flutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutterflutter  '),
                  ],
                )),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing do with your layouts, and more to do with the size of the subtitle text.
In this case, I would suggest to add a maximum line number count on the **Subtitle** attribute of the **ListTile** Widget, thus so that if the number of words exceeds a certain point, it will not ruin the position of the Star widget & the '3 dots' widget.

Looking at this, 3 lines as the max line number should be enough.